# Color Options from Theme Customizer API not returning via get_theme_mod()

Tags: themes, theme-options, child-theme, settings-api, theme-customizer

I am working with the [Theme Customizer API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API) and am going crazy trying to find the stored values.  The values successfully save and update on the front-end, so they are obviously registered successfully, however, I'm storing the options as theme specific via this method where `$this_theme` is set as `$this_theme = preg_split('/themes\//', get_stylesheet_directory_uri())[1];`.  The following code is inside of a `foreach` loop and iterating over a multi-dimensional array with all of the variable metadata for each option (referenced below as `$param['foo']`).

I'm using this method for dropdown options for font selection and also for colors, but when doing `get_theme_mod($this_theme . '_theme_options')` the returned results show the font dropdown options but not the `WP_Customize_Color_Control` options.  I'm going crazy trying to find a divergence between the two and have not found any.  Thanks so much!

```
    $wp_customize->add_setting( $this_theme . '_theme_options['. $setting .']', array(
        'default' => $param['default'],
        'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_hex_color',
        'type' => 'option',
        'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
        'priority' => $i

    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_control(
        new WP_Customize_Color_Control(
            $wp_customize,
            $this_theme . '_theme_options_'. $setting,
            array(
                'label'     => $param['label'],
                'section'   => $param['section'],
                'settings'  => $this_theme . '_theme_options['. $setting  .']',
                'priority'  => $i
            )
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your settings are stored as **Theme Mods**, rather than as a **Settings API option**, then you need to pass [the appropriate value to the `type` parameter to `$wp_customize->add_setting()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Manager/add_setting):

- `'option'`: Settings API option (`get_option()`)
- `'theme_mod'`: Theme Mods API option (`get_theme_mod()`)

Try changing this:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( $this_theme . '_theme_options['. $setting .']', array(
    'default' => $param['default'],
    'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_hex_color',
    'type' => 'option',
    'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
    'priority' => $i

) );
```

...to this:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( $this_theme . '_theme_options['. $setting .']', array(
    'default' => $param['default'],
    'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_hex_color',
    // CHANGE ME HERE
    'type' => 'theme_mod',
    'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
    'priority' => $i

) );
```

Comment: I had a feeling that could be it, but everywhere in the documentation told me not to do this.  I'll try it now and report back :)

Comment: Ok, that works... partially.  The odd result is that saving a new value via color picker causes it to appear in the returned result of `get_theme_mod()`, but I have 5 color options and only the one with a new value saved is returned.  No worries if you're not sure either, but since I have your ear I figured I would ask.  Your answer is correct regardless and much appreciated!

Comment: Ignore that question, for inquiring minds, I had been led to believe by some docs that the preference for declaring color variables was without the preceding `#` hash.  In fact, the default declarations were failing because the correct format is *with* hash character, e.g. `#fff`.

Answer (score 0):

if you add a setting using 
    'type' => 'option',
then you'll have to use get_option instead of get_theme_mod.
See this great article to learn more: http://ottopress.com/2012/how-to-leverage-the-theme-customizer-in-your-own-themes/